Vulkan compute shader synchronization
In my application I use a Compute Shader to elaborate data in a fast way. I dispatch a Compute Shader for each instance of my model. So for example, I have 30 instancies, I dispatch a Compute Shader 30 times.
for(int i = 0; i < engineModLoader.instanceNumber; i++)
{   
    engineRenderer.DispatchCompute(phoenixMesh.totalMeshlets.size(), selectedMeshlet, 
    engineModLoader.instancesData[i].instancePos);
}

I use the result of the compute shader to fill a Global Index Buffer useful for the drawing of instances. So, all Compute Shaders dispatched have to be termineted before the DrawFrame() call, which renders the instances. How could wait on the CPU the termination of a Compute Shader ?
Until now I tried to synchronize my compute shader in this way, but I get wrong data:
void Renderer::DispatchCompute(int numberOfElements, std::vector<Phoenix::DataToCompute>& selectedMeshlet, 
    const glm::vec3& instancePos)
    {
        VkSubmitInfo computeSubmitInfo{};
        computeSubmitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
        vkWaitForFences(engineDevice.logicalDevice, 1, &computeInFlightFences[currentComputeFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);

        engineTransform.ubo.instancePos = instancePos;
        UpdateUniformBuffer(currentComputeFrame);  
        vkResetFences(engineDevice.logicalDevice, 1, &computeInFlightFences[currentComputeFrame]);
        vkResetCommandBuffer(computeCommandBuffers[currentComputeFrame], 0);
        RecordComputeBuffer(numberOfElements, computeCommandBuffers[currentComputeFrame]);

        computeSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
        computeSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &computeCommandBuffers[currentComputeFrame];
        computeSubmitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        computeSubmitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = &computeSemaphores[currentComputeFrame];

        if (vkQueueSubmit(engineDevice.computeQueue, 1, &computeSubmitInfo, computeInFlightFences[currentComputeFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) 
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit compute command buffer!");
        }

        VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(Phoenix::DataToCompute) * numberOfElements;

        VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
        VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
        
        CreateBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT,
        VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
        stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);
        CopyBuffer(SSBOBuffers[currentComputeFrame], stagingBuffer, bufferSize, 
        &computeSemaphores[currentComputeFrame]);


        void* bufferData = nullptr;
        vkMapMemory(engineDevice.logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &bufferData);
        memcpy(selectedMeshlet.data(), bufferData, bufferSize);
        vkUnmapMemory(engineDevice.logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory); 
        
        currentComputeFrame = (currentComputeFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;

        vkDestroyBuffer(engineDevice.logicalDevice, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
        vkFreeMemory(engineDevice.logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
        
    }
    void Renderer::RecordComputeBuffer(int numberOfElements, VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer)
    {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo{};
        beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;

        if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) 
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
        }

        VkDeviceSize ssboSize = sizeof(Phoenix::DataToCompute) * numberOfElements;

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, enginePipeline.computePipeline);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, enginePipeline.computePipelineLayout, 0, 1, 
        &descriptorSets[currentComputeFrame], 0, 0);

        vkCmdDispatch(commandBuffer, numberOfElements / 32, 1, 1);

        if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) 
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
        }
    
    }

Where I'm going wrong ?


How could wait on the CPU the termination of a Compute Shader ?

You absolutely should not.
You don't need the CPU to wait for the compute shader; you need the GPU to wait for the compute shader. You should dispatch your compute shader operations, then use a dependency to synchronize between those and the processes that consume it. This dependency lives in your command buffer or your batches, not in CPU code.

Where I'm going wrong ?

There's a lot wrong, but one of the most obvious is that you're destroying memory before you've actually used it. You used the memory in a copy operation, but you deleted the memory before submitting that copy to the queue and ensuring that the queue finished using it.
That's bad.
The validation layers should have caught this easily.
Also, don't allocate memory just for a short operation like this. Allocate a big chunk of device memory and sub-allocate from that.

Sorry.. but I'm not destroying memory before to use it. I do the memcpy I unmap the memory and then I destroy the memory. The transfer operation is done before the destruction operation... I need to wait on the CPU because I want to use the result of my Compute Shader for further operations on the CPU. In this case, could I use a Memory Barrier to ensure me that the  SSBOBuffers[currentComputeFrame] is updated correctly after the compute dispatch ?

@Giuseppe: "The transfer operation is done before the destruction operation" The transfer operation hasn't started yet. Transfer operations are queue operations, so you have to submit a batch containing a command buffer that does a transfer. Until that batch has completed, the transfer isn't done.

I submit the vkCopyCmd to a queue within CopyBuffer() method

@Giuseppe: If you submit the copy command before actually putting the data in the memory to be copied, then your code cannot work. At least, not unless the command buffer waits for a host event to signal when to start the copy. And I don't see any place after you copy into the memory but before it's deleted where you set an event. Somewhere between the memcpy and vkDestroyBuffer, you must do something to tell the GPU to execute the copy and the CPU must wait until the GPU has performed the copy. You do neither of those.

Ok I undestand what you are saing. I need to be sure that the SSBO is updated before coping his content in the staging buffer, so I need to wait the Comput Shader execution before to perform the copy operation. Is it right no ? In CopyBuffer method I execute a vkQueueWaitIdle(), so the CPU should wait the copy termination
